# how to log raw JSON response with RestKit 0.2x

Tags: iphone, restkit, restkit-0.20

with `RestKit 0.2x` the `RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelTrace);` statement displays various mapping info with the returned `JSON` response but all things are mixed up together which is hard for me to extract the raw `JSON` body alone.
is there a way to log ONLY the returned `JSON` body without extra info with it ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a logging code in RKNSJSONSerialization's method

```
+ (id)objectFromData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError **)error
```

or better solution would be to subclass RKNSJSONSerialization and add the logging code.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear exactly what you're looking for. The trace log does print the entire JSON before the mapping starts.

Alternatively, you could edit `RKMapperOperation` to do additional logging or just use AFNetworking to download and log the JSON.

Comment: OK, I grabbed the whole JSON that's logged before the mapping starts (using the trace level log statement in the question), but it sounds an invalid JSON structure, I copied that structure and pasted into many only JSON parsers but they do not recognize it.

Comment: Logged after the deserialisation so it's not a JSON log at that point in time. Why do you need the log? You might be better off using Charles to intercept the raw incoming data...

Comment: I need it for debuting purposes, why to use such third party tool, there must be an obvious option in RestKit to display raw JSON.